# Terrafrom: How to query AWS ACM certificate with additional names?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Assuming that there is AWS ACM certificate with "additional names"

is it possible to query certificate ARN with one of the domains in the "additional names"?

This is the code im using:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"
}

data "aws_acm_certificate" "domain_cert" {
  domain   = "*.bla.bla.com"
  most_recent = true
}
```

the code will work only when `*.bla.bla.com` is your main domain, if its one of the additional names, this code will fail.

any ideas?

Comment: This would probably need to be a feature request.

Comment: There is an existing feature request for this [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4877)